# Split files into groups based on part of their name and zip them

Tags: bash, shell, zip, substring

I have a folder containing several files using naming convention like this (4 parts divided by underscore):

> Part1_Part2_Part3_Part4.csv

for example:

> AAA_XXX_AAA001_20991231.csv
>   AAA_XXX_AAA001_20991131.csv
>   AAA_XXX_AAA002_20991031.csv
>   AAA_XXX_AAA002_20990931.csv
>   BBB_XXX_BBB001_20991231.csv
>   BBB_XXX_BBB001_20991131.csv
>   BBB_XXX_BBB002_20991031.csv
>   BBB_XXX_BBB002_20990931.csv

I need to create a shell script, which groups them based on substrings Part1 and Part3 and creates a zip archive using naming convention like this:

> Part1_Part3.zip

For example zip file called

> "AAA_AAA001.zip" should contain files:
>
> AAA_XXX_AAA001_20991231.csv
>   AAA_XXX_AAA001_20991131.csv
>
> "AAA_AAA002.zip" should contain files:
>
> AAA_XXX_AAA002_20991231.csv
>   AAA_XXX_AAA002_20991131.csv
>
> The same as above with "BBB_BBBXXX.zip".

The structure of the files is fixed. Part1 is always at start and Part3 is always following the second underscore. The number of characters can vary though.

I'm completely new to shell scripting. I've spent several hours trying working with string, zipping files, etc., but I'm not able to use this knowledge to come up with a complete solution like this.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something like `ls *_*_*.csv | cut -d- -f1,3 | sort -u` or another way to find substrings?

Comment: @WalterA I did. I was able to find substrings, but I don't know how to actually loop the files based on these substrings, group them and zip them.

Comment: Not tested: `ls *_*_*.csv | cut -d- -f1,3 | sort -u| while IFS=_ read -r part1 part3; do echo "zipfile ${part1}_${part3}.zip"; echo "Files ${part1}_*_${part3}_*.csv";done`, something like this?

Comment: @WalterA Thank you very much for this. I've ran the script just now and this is exactly how the files should be distributed into zips. Now I need to somehow figure out how to actually zip them like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all combinations part1-part3 and make that an unique list.
You can add your own options to `zip`, I think you want something like

```
ls *_*_*.csv | cut -d_ -f1,3 | sort -u| while IFS=_ read -r part1 part3; do 
   echo "zipfile ${part1}_${part3}.zip"
   echo "Files ${part1}_*_${part3}_*.csv"
   zip ${part1}_${part3}.zip ${part1}_*_${part3}_*.csv
done
```

Edit: Corrected typo as suggested in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's working. I marked it as an answer, but you just need to fix the typo in `cut -d-`, it should be `cut -d_` in my case.